# How can I make python unittest failures not print the entire test?

Tags: python, python-unittest

When using my python unit tests, sometimes my tests become somewhat long due to test-specific inputs, or other lengthy logic.
If one of my tests fail, unittest will print out the entire test, from the top of the list down to the assertion failure. The problem is that if my test is long for any reason, then when the test fails, the output becomes kind of a nuisance to scroll through.

Does anyone know of a way to make python unittest still show the assertion failure, but NOT print the entire test case?

E.G. for test:

```
    def testArbitraryStringTest(self):
        arbStrings = [
            'abcdef',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'as',
        ]
        for arbStr in arbStrings:
            self.assertGreater(len(arbStr), 3)
```

instead of output:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

SemanticTest.py::SemanticTest::testArbitraryStringTest FAILED            [100%]
SemanticTest.py:15 (SemanticTest.testArbitraryStringTest)
self = <SemanticTest.SemanticTest testMethod=testArbitraryStringTest>

    def testArbitraryStringTest(self):
        arbStrings = [
            'abcdef',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'asvnoiasdv;',
            '1a23',
            '12l;kf3j',
            'va;kljda',
            'roenwfas',
            'asdjvoisdp',
            'v9jw3oawe',
            'a;lvnpaos',
            'vaoispvdjdas',
            'avnoasdpf',
            'voasdivpas',
            'as',
        ]
        for arbStr in arbStrings:
>           self.assertGreater(len(arbStr), 3)
E           AssertionError: 2 not greater than 3

SemanticTest.py:65: AssertionError






============================== 1 failed in 0.34s ===============================
```

It would be nice to have something more like:

```
============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

SemanticTest.py::SemanticTest::testArbitraryStringTest FAILED            [100%]
E           AssertionError: 2 not greater than 3

SemanticTest.py:65: AssertionError





============================== 1 failed in 0.34s ===============================
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: are you sure it is unittest run? looks like pytest

Comment: The test class inherits from unittest.TestCase class SemanticTest(unittest.TestCase):
*EDIT*
It does use pytest. Here is the console command:
Launching pytest with arguments SemanticTest.py::SemanticTest::testArbitraryStringTest --no-header --no-summary -q in /Users/userT/learn-projects

Comment: Really, that should be 45 separate tests, not a single test that makes 45 different assertions. (Frameworks usually provide someway of defining multiple tests using a single function but multiple "inputs".)

Comment: yes, I got it. however this kind of output is provided by pytest runner. unittest tests can be run by pytest. How are you running your test file in terminal? If it is `python tst.py` with `unittest.main()` inside then it is unittest run. If you run it as `pytest tst.py` then pytest runner is used. If you run it with PyCharm, which has autodetect option, it still can use pytest by default. Have a look at my answer. There I mentioned how default unittest output looks like when I run your test.

Comment: I see your comment UPD. looks like you are executing it with PyCharm which uses pytest. Ok you can add `--tb=short` to your Configuration's Additional Arguments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe unittest does not have such traceback by default:

```
F
======================================================================
FAIL: testArbitraryStringTest (__main__.Test1)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\repos\stackoverflow\tst.py", line 52, in testArbitraryStringTest
    self.assertGreater(len(arbStr), 3)
AssertionError: 2 not greater than 3

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.000s

FAILED (failures=1)
```

Seems like you are using `pytest` which has `--tb` cli option.

You can use it as `pytest --tb=short` so it will have following output:

```
============================= test session starts =============================
collecting ... collected 1 item

tst.py::Test1::testArbitraryStringTest FAILED                           [100%]
tst.py:2 (Test1.testArbitraryStringTest)
tst.py:52: in testArbitraryStringTest
    self.assertGreater(len(arbStr), 3)
E   AssertionError: 2 not greater than 3

============================== 1 failed in 0.06s ==============================
```

As you are using PyCharm: one of possible options to pass this argument is `Configuration -> Additional Arguments`
[image: Configuration]

Comment: btw you can add `--tb=short` option to `addopts` section of your `pytest.ini` file of `PYTEST_ADDOPTS` environment variable so all of your runs have this by default